# Assigning factor labels and levels within a function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(janitor)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(date = c("1/28/2022", "1/25/2022", "1/27/2022", "1/23/2022"), 
                   y = c(100, 25, 35, 45))
```

I need to write a function that adds a new column that sorts the date column and assigns sequential day stage (i.e., Day 1, Day 2, etc.). So far I have tried the following with no luck.

```
day.assign <- function(df){
    df2 <- clean_names(df)
    len <- length(unique(df2$date))
    
    levels.start <- as.character(sort(mdy(unique(df2$date))))
    day.label <-  paste("Day", seq(1, len, by = 1))
    
    df <- 
        df %>% 
        mutate(Date = as.character(mdy(Date)),  
               Day = as.factor(Date, 
                               levels = levels.start, 
                               labels = day.label))
}
```

Future files will have a various amount of dates that must be accounted for when assigning the day column (i.e., one file may have 4 dates while the next may have 6).

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(date = c("1/28/2022", "1/25/2022", "1/27/2022", "1/23/2022"), 
                   y = c(100, 25, 35, 45))

day.assign <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(Date = mdy(date)) %>% 
    arrange(mdy(date)) %>% 
    mutate(Day = paste0("Day ", row_number()))
}

day.assign(data)
#>        date   y       Date   Day
#> 1 1/23/2022  45 2022-01-23 Day 1
#> 2 1/25/2022  25 2022-01-25 Day 2
#> 3 1/27/2022  35 2022-01-27 Day 3
#> 4 1/28/2022 100 2022-01-28 Day 4
```

Comment: Thank you. That could work by creating a new data frame then joining back to the origional. Is there a way to prevent subsetting unique values and assigning them directly to the original df?